# using commands in pgfkeys not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expansion

The following latex code works as expected. It allows to draw a line parallel to the z axis:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
parallel to z axis/.code={
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointorigin}{
 \pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{1}
 }
 \edef\lineangle{\pgfmathresult}
}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around x=30,rotate around y=50]
\begin{scope}[->]
\draw(0,0)--(1,0)node[right]{$x$};
\draw (0,0)--(0,1)node[left]{$y$};
\draw[blue] (0,0)--(0,0,1)node[ right]{$z$};
\end{scope}

\draw[blue, parallel to z axis ] (-1cm,0cm)--+(\lineangle:1.5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In an attempt to  make some improvement I defined a new macro `\newcommand{\zangle}{...}` as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\zangle}{
 \expandafter\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointorigin}{
 \pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{1}}
     \pgfmathresult}

\tikzset{
parallel to z axis/.code={
 \edef\lineangle{\zangle}
}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around x=30,rotate around y=50]
\begin{scope}[->]
\draw(0,0)--(1,0)node[right]{$x$};
\draw (0,0)--(0,1)node[left]{$y$};
\draw[blue] (0,0)--(0,0,1)node[ right]{$z$};
\end{scope}

\draw[blue, parallel to z axis ] (-1cm,0cm)--+(\lineangle:1.5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But it does not work because of compilation errors!

I think  that the problem is related to the macro expansion but I have no idea how to fix it. So please Help!

Comment: Why do you consider your second version an improvement? You could set the `zangle` once and for all with `execute at begin picture` or `execute at begin scope` instead of repeatedly computing it. This might be an improvement IMHO.

Comment: because I plan to use the same code  in another part of the document. I think it is better to define a macro.

Comment: @marmot solution is very interesting but I wonder if it is possible and not very difficult to make the `\lineangle` command expand to the value computed by the `\zangle` command?

Comment: Yes, of course, with the usual tricks: `\newcommand{\zangle}[1]{
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointorigin}{
 \pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{1}}
\edef#1{\pgfmathresult}}`

`\tikzset{
parallel to z axis/.code={
\zangle{\lineangle}
}
}`. But *why* would one do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to your question:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\zangle}[1]{
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointorigin}{
 \pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{1}}
\edef#1{\pgfmathresult}}

\tikzset{
parallel to z axis/.code={
\zangle{\lineangle}
}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around x=30,rotate around y=50]
\begin{scope}[->]
\draw(0,0)--(1,0)node[right]{$x$};
\draw (0,0)--(0,1)node[left]{$y$};
\draw[blue] (0,0)--(0,0,1)node[ right]{$z$};
\end{scope}
\draw[blue, parallel to z axis ] (-1cm,0cm)--+(\lineangle:1.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I wouldn't do that. Here is what I would do. I don't see why you can't use this in other parts of the document, too. I'd set the `z angle` once in a scope and then just use it as often as I need it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
get z angle/.style={execute at begin scope={
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointorigin}{
 \pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{1}
 }
 \edef#1{\pgfmathresult}
}
}}


\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around x=30,rotate around y=50,get z angle=\zangle]
\begin{scope}[->]
\draw(0,0)--(1,0)node[right]{$x$};
\draw (0,0)--(0,1)node[left]{$y$};
\draw[blue] (0,0)--(0,0,1)node[ right]{$z$};
\end{scope}
\draw[blue] (-1cm,0cm)--+(\zangle:1.5cm);
\draw[red] (1cm,0cm)--+(0,0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am also not sure if I understand the purpose of all this, `--+(\zangle:1.5cm)` is equivalent to `--+(0,0,1.5)`, see the red plot. If you tell us what you really have in mind, this may lead to another view of things. Yet if it is only to "remember" the angle, you only need to say `\xdef\rememberedzangle{\zangle}` inside the `tikzpicture` to remember this value, i.e. `\rememberedzangle` may be used in future pictures.

Comment: I want to draw a line that makes a determinated angle with the horizontal line. the angle can be specified either by an angle value or by a letter x, y or z that means parralel to x , y or z. I don't know if it is comprehensible what I say. I am not used to speak english.

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda That's all fine. However, I'd like to draw your attention to the `calc` library, which is described in section 13.5  of the pgfmanual. The reason why you won't find too many posts using `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints` and so on is that everything can be done with `calc` in an arguably more elegant way. So it is possible to write macros like you propose, but on the long run I believe you will be better off switching to `calc`. Of course, I might be wrong.

Comment: Ok I will take a look at calc